# ConditionalPanels for each navbarpage in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, navbar

I have a simple problem with Shiny: I'm using a navbarPage layout, and I have two different sidebars. I want the sidebar to be conditional on which page of the app the user is on.

That seems easy enough, and the following approach works fine at changing the sidebar panel, but with this approach my tab headers drop down from the top navbar and into the main panel. I Have tried various approaches to get them back into the navbar, which all haven't worked.

Suspect there's a very simple solution, any help gratefully received!

```
library(shiny)
ui <- navbarPage(title = "example",
                 sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                   conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs==1',"sidebar 1"),
                   conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs==2 | input.tabs==3',"sidebars 2&3")),
                                    
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(id="tabs",
    
    tabPanel("About",value=1, "hello 1"),
    tabPanel("parameters",value=2, "hello 2"),
    tabPanel("outputs",value=3, "hello 3")
))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `tabsetPanel` to achieve this, just assign the `id` to the `navbarPage` itself and see which one is clicked

```
library(shiny)
ui <- navbarPage(title = "example",
                 id = 'tabs',
                 tabPanel("About",value=1, "hello 1"),
                 tabPanel("parameters",value=2, "hello 2"),
                 tabPanel("outputs",value=3, "hello 3"),
                 sidebarPanel(
                     conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs == 1',"sidebar 1"),
                     conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.tabs == 2 | input.tabs==3',"sidebars 2&3")
                 )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    observe({
        print(input$tabs)
    })   
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's a way to retain sidebarLayout() - otherwise it gets difficult (for me at least) to position the tabs and sidebar alongside one another.

Comment: `sidebarLayout` requires `mainPanel` so if u want that u need to create `mainPanel` in each `tabPanel`